# Multiple doubled JOIN to the same table

Tags: sql, informix

Example 1 (works fine, selects **assignedagent**):

```
select cr.callid, cr.callstart, cr.callend, cr.waittime, cr.origin,
cr.origdestination, cr.waitresolution, cr.contacttype, cr.termtype,
u.userlastname as assignedagentname,
"" as answeringagentname from callrecord cr
left join (agentrecord ar left join users u on ar.agentkey=u.userkey)
on (cr.callid=ar.callid and cr.assignedagent=ar.sequencenumber);
```

Example 2 (works fine, selects **answeringagent**):

```
select cr.callid, cr.callstart, cr.callend, cr.waittime, cr.origin,
cr.origdestination, cr.waitresolution, cr.contacttype, cr.termtype,
"" as assignedagentname,
u.userlastname as answeringagentname from callrecord cr
left join (agentrecord ar left join users u on ar.agentkey=u.userkey)
on (cr.callid=ar.callid and cr.answeringagent=ar.sequencenumber);
```

Example 3 (produces an error, selects both):

```
select cr.callid, cr.callstart, cr.callend, cr.waittime, cr.origin,
cr.origdestination, cr.waitresolution, cr.contacttype, cr.termtype,
u1.userlastname as assignedagentname,
u2.userlastname as answeringagentname from callrecord cr
left join (agentrecord ar left join users u1 on ar.agentkey=u1.userkey)
on (cr.callid=ar.callid and cr.assignedagent=ar.sequencenumber)
left join (agentrecord ar left join users u2 on ar.agentkey=u2.userkey)
on (cr.callid=ar.callid and cr.answeringagent=ar.sequencenumber);
```

Examples 1 and 2 work fine and returns true results. In example 3 I have followed advice about aliasing for multiple joins found in this forum, but without success. I work with Informix DB via ODBC driver.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you want and what the issue seems to be?

Comment: Did you try change de alias of "ar" from the each left join? Just like you did with u1, u2

Comment: @ceinmart, your advice have solved the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the parentheses and being sure that all aliases are unique:

```
select cr.callid, cr.callstart, cr.callend, cr.waittime, cr.origin,
       cr.origdestination, cr.waitresolution, cr.contacttype, cr.termtype,
       u1.userlastname as assignedagentname,
       u2.userlastname as answeringagentname
from callrecord cr left join
     agentrecord ar1
     on cr.callid = ar1.callid and
        cr.assignedagent = ar1.sequencenumber left join
     users u1
     on ar.agentkey = u1.userkey left join
     agentrecord ar2 
     on cr.callid = ar2.callid and 
        cr.answeringagent = ar2.sequencenumber left join
     users u2 on ar2.agentkey = u2.userkey
```

Comment: Gordon Linoff, great thanks for the true answer and for improving my code! This works 100%